# Double jQuery validation of 2 decimal inputs and getting the bigger number

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, double

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("cents", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d{0,12}(\.\d{0,2})?$/i.test(value); 
    }, "You must include two decimal places");

    $.validator.addMethod('lessthan', function(value, element, param) {
          return this.optional(element) || value <= $(param).val();
    }, 'Invalid value');
    $.validator.addMethod('greaterthan', function(value, element, param) {
          return this.optional(element) || value >= $(param).val();
    }, 'Invalid value');

    $("#globalSettingsFormId").validate({
        rules: {

        //  Validation Rules
            minBetAmt: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                cents: true,
                lessthan: '#maxBetAmt'

            },
            maxBetAmt: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                cents: true,
                greaterthan: '#minBetAmt'
            }

        submitHandler: function(form){
                form.submit();
        },
   messages: {
            minBetAmt:{
                required: "minimum bet amount required!",
                number: "This must be a number!",
                cents: "You must include two decimal places",
                lessthan: 'Minimum Bet Amount must be less than Max Bet Amount!'
            },
            maxBetAmt: {
                required: "Max bet amount required!!",
                number: "This must be a number!",
                cents: "You must include two decimal places",
                greaterthan: "Max Bet Amount must be greater than Min Bet Amount!"
            }
    });
```

---

When my inputs are minBetAmt=25.55 and maxBetAmt = 26.5, my form validates and submits.
But when I change my maxBetAmt to 241.55 or 2400.25, this message comes out: "Max Bet Amount must be greater than Min Bet Amount!"

It seems like there's something wrong with my addMethods. Some people told me that there's something wrong within the return value of my method 'cents'.

Can you help me guys to figure out what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The comment implies the two decimal places are required, but your regex says 0 to 2 decimal places. Can you confirm which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the strings' collation order, not values. e.g. "25" is greater than "24000" as "5" is greater than "4" in the second character.

Convert the values to floating point *number* values before comparison.

```
$.validator.addMethod('lessthan', function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || parseFloat(value) <= parseFloat($(param).val());
}, 'Invalid value');
$.validator.addMethod('greaterthan', function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || parseFloat(value) >= parseFloat($(param).val());
}, 'Invalid value');
```

Simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6g00am3c/1/

```
console.log("25" > "2400");
console.log(25.00 > 2400);
```

(check the console output)

```
true
false
```

Comment: Thank you @TrueBlueAussie. It's working properly now. :)